# Git: reset --hard now I'm stuck in the past

Tags: git

I was messing about with `reset` after reading stuff in the Pro Git book.

I basically ended up doing a `reset --hard` to a revision 12 commits previous.

I can't seem to get back to the present, or the latest commit. I've tried `reset` using `ORIG_HEAD` and even feeding it in the sha1 of the revision to go forward to.

Running `git status` I get:
Your branch is behind by 12 commits and can be fast-forwarded.

How do I move HEAD back to the latest commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though you've already pushed the 12 commits you reset. If that's the case, then

```
git merge --ff-only REMOTE/BRANCH_NAME
```

should work where `REMOTE` is the name of the remote (commonly `origin`) and `BRANCH_NAME` is the name of your current branch.

Comment: That did it, even without network access! Cool, though wish I really understood how it can merge with a remote branch even thought it can't connect?

Comment: `merge`s are local operations (it's the `fetch` that requires a network connection).

Answer (score 13):

Use the reflog to find out where you want to go. You can get it using `git reflog` and then just reset to the appropriate commit. Assuming you haven't done anything since you did the reset,

```
git reset --hard 'HEAD@{1}'
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to help. The latest commit shown by reflog is the revision I'm currently on, it doesn't show the 12 missing ones :(

Comment: What does the previous one show? reflog tracks the changes to the HEAD .

Comment: I ran `git reset --hard 'HEAD@{1}'` and now according to `git status` I'm now only 11 commits behind :)

Comment: What do you get when you do a `git reflog`. You should get the list of commits and you can simply `git reset` to the right one.

Comment: HEAD@{0} Shows me --hard resetting to historical commit. All the way down to HEAD@{17} which shows me cloning a branch (the beginning). So the 11/12 commits are not listed.

Comment: No. When you do a `git reflog`, you will get a list of commits at which `HEAD` pointed to. `HEAD@{n}` will be the `n`th older commit. You will have the previous position of HEAD in the list of commits, `git reset --hard` to that. I can't really describe it more clearly than that.

Comment: Of course you are right and I'm being a numpty. New to Stackoverflow so I'll have a fiddle and try to give you lots of rep :) If you have a min would you kindly have a quick look at my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213926/git-simplest-way-of-squashing-commits-on-master)? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is one of these answers I wish I could upvote twice - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Another way (beside reflog) would be to use the fact that your branch seems to be referenced on the `remotes` namespace side, as a remote branch, which is why you see:

```
Your branch is behind by 12 commits and can be fast-forwarded.
```

A simple

```
git merge origin/yourBranch
```

should be enough to fast-forward the `HEAD` of your local branch back to where your remote branch was.