# Git: simplest way of squashing commits on master

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I squash my last X commits together using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-can-i-squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

I have a project hosted on GitHub and I have a local clone. I have a load of small commits that I have already pushed up to GitHub. This has all been done using the default *master branch.

I got confused between merge --squash and rebase etc...
What is the most straightforward way of combining several historial commits in to one commit so that it pushes up to GitHub?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Before starting, you should make sure that `git status` is clean (i.e. there's no output from that command) to avoid losing work.  The simplest way to do what you want is probably:

```
git reset --soft <LAST-COMMIT-THAT'S-OK>
git commit -m 'Many squashed commits'
git push --force origin master
```

You should bear in mind that this is rewriting history (that's why you need the `--force` option to `git push`) so you should avoid this if anyone else might have cloned or pulled from your repository.  For some more alternatives, see this question and its answers:

- [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/223092)

Comment: What are the repercussions of doing this if other branches regularly pull from the repo (fast forwarding only)?

Comment: @whoami: If someone else pulls that branch, they will see `(forced update)` and git will refuse to update their branch.  They then need to (a) make sure that all their work is committed (b) typically either rebase (e.g. with `git rebase origin/master`) or reset their branch to the remote-tracking branch version that's just been force-updated (e.g. with `git reset --hard origin/master`).  Unless you're happy explaining to people what to do, it's definitely best not to force-push rewritten history.

Comment: They will all see that their local branches and the remote have diverged and will have to merge the changes in rather than just fast forward.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: The problem with merging in that situation is that they will still have all the small commits in their merged `master` branch, and might push them back to the repository.

Comment: Urgh sounds a bit messy either way, I suppose the moral of the story is to do it all before it goes on GitHub? In that case is `reset --soft` or `rebase` most suitable?

Comment: @whoami: Yes, it's best to restrict history rewriting to commits that you haven't pushed yet.  If you know exactly that you want to squash all the last N commits, `reset --soft` and committing is probably easier, but if you want to selectively squash and reorder commits, using `git rebase -i` will give you that flexibility.  (Also it depends which commands you're more familiar with...)

Comment: @Gabe Whenever I force push a branch, I let everyone working on that branch know about it. Then they can `git branch -D branchname && git checkout branchname && git pull` which will delete their copy of the branch and checkout a fresh copy. We prevent any pushing to `master` and do all work on a feature branch. So only people working on the same feature branch are affected.

Comment: @MarkLongair Can you add a note about the `HEAD~5` syntax when selecting a commit?